# Segmentation fault на все команды

Tags: linux, centos, centos6

Я ставил glibc 2.16 по [этой](https://github.com/FezVrasta/ark-server-tools/wiki/Install-of-required-versions-of-glibc-and-gcc-on-RHEL-CentOS) инструкции. Сделал первые два раздела и после `make install` у меня все сломалось... Ни работает ни одна команда!!! Ни `make uninstall` ни даже просто `ls`. На все пишет `segmentation fault`. Что важно - это прод с кучей сайтов. Помогите пожалуйста! Надо срочно починить, и без ребута желательно!

Comment: я пока вижу только один способ - это найти сервер с такой же конфигурацией (да хоть в виртуалке поднять) и просто покопировать нужные файлы.Но для этого нужна рабочая команда копирования - scp или rsync.

Comment: @KoVadim в принципе я могу зайти туда по SFTP с файлового менеджера (точнее уже зашел). Но что копировать? Конкретно?? Я просто не знаю...

Comment: я так понимаю, что дошли до команды `sudo make install` для glibc Либо смотреть, что оно копирует, либо просто попробовать промотать терминал вверх и там будет видно.  Я у себя подсмотрел список файлов https://www.pastiebin.com/5a780f89467d7 - думаю, что нужно начать с папок /lib lib32 lib64 и /etc   И не забудьте сделать предварительно бекап!!!

Comment: Ууу, батенька, вам не позавидуешь. Вы снесли (в лучшем случае симлинки) зависимости от glibc. А от нее зависит чуть менее чем вся ОС. *ldd* вам в помощь для начала. Либо попробуйте переинсталить (хотя пока не знаю как если все команды поломаны) родную glibc из репозитария.

Comment: Отбой паники. Оказалось что это только виртуалка и есть куча бэкапов. Я просто не в курсе был.

Comment: Делать из центоси слаку\лфс? Ну так себе идея. Хотя бы через `checkinstall`. https://habrahabr.ru/post/130868/